# Flutter - How scroll to SliverPersistentHeader position?

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, customscrollview

```
CustomScrollView(
     SliverToBoxAdapter(), // firstBox
     SliverPersistentHeader(pinned:true),
     SliverToBoxAdapter(), // secondBox
)
```

I have a button on this page, when I click this button, how let SliverPersistentHeader scroll to top programmatically? 
Addition: firstBox's height is uncertain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initalize a GlobalKey in that widget.

```
    final GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
```

Then pass it to the widget you want to scroll to:

```
  CustomScrollView(
   slivers: [
     SliverToBoxAdapter(), // firstBox
     SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true, delegate: null,),
     SliverToBoxAdapter(
       key: globalKey,
     ),
   ],
 )
```

Then the button onPressed should be like this:

```
  onPressed: () {
            Scrollable.ensureVisible(
            globalKey.currentContext!,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            );
        },
```